# Preimage of the product of two functions, Tonelli-Fubini's Theorem, Measurable functions.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $F=fg$ where $f,g $ are functions. What is the relation between the preimage of $F$ and the preimage of $f$ and $g$ ?

Just in case, if you are able to understand the following, the main problem that i'm trying to solve is,

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function, define $F:\mathbb{R}^{2n}\to \mathbb{R}$ by $F(x,y)=\chi_{Q_i}(x)f(x)-\chi_{2Q}(y)f(x+y)$ where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $\chi_{Q_1},\chi_{Q_2}$ is the characteristic function of the open cubes $Q_1,Q_2\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable, then $F$ is measurable.

and i'm also trying to solve this for be able to use Tonelli-Fubini's theorem for the following integral,
$$\int\limits_{Q_1}\int\limits_{Q_2}\lvert f(x)-f(x+y)\rvert^p dydx$$
where $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R^n})$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:    $fg=\frac{(f+g)^2 - f^2 - g^2}{2}$ This helps for seeing $F$ is measurable.

Don't expect to find a relationship between preimage of $F$ and preimages of $f, g$! Since $F$ does not have uniue representation ! for example :

$$F=fg= e^xf  \times e^{-x}g$$

Comment: @hardmath  did you read the rest of the problem ?  It indeed helps to prove $F$ is measurable.

Comment: I upvoted since you make a couple of good points, but if I were allowed to make a suggestion, articulate the fundamental lemmas or propositions which imply the revised expression is measurable.  You could still be leaving it to Readers to work out how these apply, but if measurability of $fg$ is in doubt, there ought to be justification for $f^2$ or $g^2$ being measurable.

Comment: @hardmath  measurability of $f^2$ is same as $|f|$: let $a,b $ are positive number then

$$a< f^2 <b  \to  \sqrt a   < |f| <  \sqrt b   \to   \sqrt a < f  ~ \cup ~ f < - \sqrt a ~\cup.... $$

Comment: Indeed, I just realize my first question is really naive, and the second one is really bad formulated, but the thrid one, that integral where I'm trying to apply Fubini-Tonelli's theorem is the one that I need to answer, I need to justify why that function $(x,y)\to f(x+y)-f(x)$ is measurable in $R^{2n}$, which is the big integration space. I remark my knowledged in product spaces is kind of null. If anyone can explain me, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, I just realize my first question is really naive, and the second one is really bad formulated, but the thrid one, that integral where I'm trying to apply Fubini-Tonelli's theorem is the one that I need to answer, I need to justify why that function $(x,y)\to f(x+y)-f(x)$ is measurable in $R^{2n}$, which is the big integration space. I remark my knowledged in product spaces is kind of null. If anyone can explain me, I would appreciate it.